# Is it heavier to iterate through an empty table in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

Case1: iterating through a pre-sized table

```
local t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
for i = 1, 10 do
  t[i] = i * 2
end
```

Case2: iterating through an empty table

```
local t = {}
for i = 1, 10 do
  t[i] = i * 2
end
```

Would there be any performance difference between performing the two loops?

Does Lua internally resize the table before assigning a value?

Comment: The performance difference between these sorts of things is the kind of thing you're *not* supposed to think about when using a scripting language. If you're trying to optimize trivial cases like that, then you're probably doing something wrong. Just write the code in whatever way gets the point across and move on.

Comment: @NicolBolas What if the table gets big and the difference is huge? I'm asking this question because it can affect my design decision. If `case2` is slower, I can make the table variable outside the function scope so it can be reused without having to be resized everytime I call the function.

Comment: "*What if the table gets big and the difference is huge?*" Are you willing to put a *gigantic* placeholder table containing dozens or hundreds of elements into the middle of your code? Is that a thing you want to make people read? Are you willing to maintain code with giant tables in the middle of it (keeping the number of elements up-to-date with the code using it)? You're using a *scripting language*; if performance was that important to you, you should be using C or C++ or something instead of Lua. It should not affect your design decisions.

Comment: You might be interested in this e-book sample from the Lua website: [Lua Performance Tips](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf)

Comment: @Adam Thank you so much! It will be helpful.

Comment: In addition to other comments, there should be some fixed-size array libraries out there which can improve performance.